# Discord.py Play Gtts Without Saving The Audio File

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code that converts text to audio and saves it as a mp3, then joins a voice channel and plays the audio file

```py
@commands.command()
async def tts(self, ctx, *, text):
     sound = gtts(text=text, lang="en", slow=False).save("test.mp3")
     channel=voice_channel.name
     await ctx.send('User is in channel: '+ channel)
     vc = await voice_channel.connect()
     vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('test.mp3'), after=print("Done"))
```

How would I do this without saving the text to speech and just playing it straight from the gtts

Comment: Good conversation about this here:

https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/26

Answer (score 0):

In the [gTTS documentation](https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#playing-sound-directly) you can find instructions for playing a sound directly. And in the [discord.py API documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.FFmpegPCMAudio) you see that there is a `pipe` parameter that can be set to `True` for the `FFmpegPCMAudio` method.

However, the `FFmpegPCMAudio` method appears to not work as it should for this purpose, and @Armster15 has given [a working solution](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5192#issuecomment-669515571) on a discord.py issue for this. You may copy his code to a file (e.g. `FFmpegPCMAudioGTTS.py`) and rename the class name to `FFmpegPCMAudioGTTS` for clarity, because this method will not work for normal streams (only for gTTS).

Thus, your code can become:

```py
from FFmpegPCMAudioGTTS import FFmpegPCMAudioGTTS

@commands.command()
async def tts(self, ctx, *, text):
    sound = gtts(text=text, lang="en", slow=False)
    sound_fp = BytesIO()
    sound.write_to_fp(sound_fp)
    channel = voice_channel.name
    await ctx.send('User is in channel: ' + channel)
    vc = await voice_channel.connect()
    vc.play(FFmpegPCMAudioGTTS(sound_fp.read(), pipe=True), after=print("Done"))
```

`FFmpegPCMAudioGTTS.py`

```py
import subprocess
import shlex
import io
from discord.opus import Encoder
import discord

class FFmpegPCMAudioGTTS(discord.AudioSource):
    def __init__(self, source, *, executable='ffmpeg', pipe=False, stderr=None, before_options=None, options=None):
        stdin = None if not pipe else source
        args = [executable]
        if isinstance(before_options, str):
            args.extend(shlex.split(before_options))
        args.append('-i')
        args.append('-' if pipe else source)
        args.extend(('-f', 's16le', '-ar', '48000', '-ac', '2', '-loglevel', 'warning'))
        if isinstance(options, str):
            args.extend(shlex.split(options))
        args.append('pipe:1')
        self._process = None
        try:
            self._process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=stderr)
            self._stdout = io.BytesIO(
                self._process.communicate(input=stdin)[0]
            )
        except FileNotFoundError:
            raise discord.ClientException(executable + ' was not found.') from None
        except subprocess.SubprocessError as exc:
            raise discord.ClientException('Popen failed: {0.__class__.__name__}: {0}'.format(exc)) from exc
    def read(self):
        ret = self._stdout.read(Encoder.FRAME_SIZE)
        if len(ret) != Encoder.FRAME_SIZE:
            return b''
        return ret
    def cleanup(self):
        proc = self._process
        if proc is None:
            return
        proc.kill()
        if proc.poll() is None:
            proc.communicate()

        self._process = None
```